# Modify html after paste image into CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

when I pasted image into CKEditor it is going well the images is uploaded to the server and show in CKEditor. How can I modify html when it already uploaded and the images show on CKEditor. when I pasted image the html source is like this

```
<p><img src="upload/images/tes.png  " style="height:768px; width:1366px" /></p>
```

How can I modify to be like this

```
<div class="imagebox">
   <p><img src="upload/images/tes.png" class="mylightbox" style="height:300px; width:600px" /></p>
</div>
```

My CKEditor setting

```
<script>
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: "browse.php",
    filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php?responseType=json"
});

editor.on('fileUploadResponse', function(evt) {
    // Prevent the default response handler.
    evt.stop();

    // Get XHR and response.
    var data = evt.data,
        xhr = data.fileLoader.xhr,
        response = xhr.responseText.split('|');

    if (response[1]) {
        // An error occurred during upload.
        data.message = response[1];
        evt.cancel();
    } else {
        data.url = response[0];
    }
});
</script>
```

and my `upload.php` code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'])){
// Required: anonymous function reference number as explained above.
$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;
// Optional: instance name (might be used to load a specific configuration 
file or anything else).
$CKEditor = $_GET['CKEditor'] ;
// Optional: might be used to provide localized messages.
$langCode = $_GET['langCode'] ;
// Optional: compare it with the value of `ckCsrfToken` sent in a cookie to 
protect your server side uploader against CSRF.
// Available since CKEditor 4.5.6.
$token = $_POST['ckCsrfToken'] ;
// Check the $_FILES array and save the file. Assign the correct path to a 
variable ($url).
$url = 'tes.png';
// Usually you will only assign something here if the file could not be 
uploaded.
$message = 'The uploaded file has been renamed';
echo "<script 
type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, 
'$url', '$message');</script>";     
 }else{
$filename = "tes.png";
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$target_path = $destination_path . "/upload/images/" . $filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)){
    echo "upload/images/".$filename;
}   
}
?>
```

please does anyone can help me here?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you can do something like `editor.on('paste', myCallback);` and react to it that way.

Comment: how can i modify to be like this    <div class="imagebox">
       <p><img src="upload/images/tes.png" class="mylightbox" style="height:300px; width:600px" /></p>
    </div>

Comment: After the paste event is handled, you can set the html contents of the `#imagebox` to what you need.

Comment: i think    editor.on('paste', myCallback); is not the function to handle after i pasted and uploaded the images

Comment: does the callback get called if you handle it?

Comment: after i uploaded the image?

Comment: whenever you paste anything in the edtior

Comment: when i pasted the image CKEditor create the code like this      <p><img src="upload/images/tes.png  " style="height:768px; width:1366px" /></p>. i want modify this html. can you show me how to do that with an example code?

Comment: I haven't used CKEditor, but i looked at the documentation. First, add `editor.on('paste', function() {console.log('foo'); });` and check your console log to see if anything happens.